# How did the ancient people of Scotland know about Zeta Reticuli if it's in the Southern Sky?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In Prometheus, Elizabeth Shaw and Charlie Holloway discover a star map in Scotland that matches others from several unconnected ancient cultures that leads them to the Zeta Reticuli system. How is this possible, since the system is not visible from Britain's latitude?

Comment: Because the film is appallingly written?

Comment: You watched Prometheus, presumably on purpose and **this** is your biggest issue with it? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I think I'd dozed off by that point in the film

Answer (score 7):

The implication is that the constellation is part of a series of writing that that Engineers used to communicate with ancient peoples of Earth. Note that it's not just in Scotland that this is seen but "every continent".

This was explained in the original John Spaiht script but seems to have gotten lost between page and the screen, probably because of the multiple re-writes.

> [Their finds: columns of writing on stone tablets in Egypt, China,
> Cambodia, Peru. Patterns of lines, curves, and dots.]
>
> **Holloway:** *This is the writing of the Engineers. We’ve found it on
> every continent. And last year, we found our Rosetta Stone. The
> display shows the Engineer obelisk under the sea.*
>
> **WATTS:** *The writing is a formula giving the location of a single star in our sky.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien: Engineers - Original Script](http://www.joblo.com/scripts/Alien-Engineers-ORIGINAL-PROMETHEUS-SCRIPT.pdf)</sup></sub>